# "connectedStatus" in `sf org list` command contains HTML page markup

Tags: scratch-org, cli

I ran `sf org list` command in console and saw CLI just dump a ton of invisible symbols, making terminal unusable. I then tried json output and saw that for scratch orgs I got a huge output with HTML markup:

```
{
  "accessToken": ...,
  "instanceUrl": "https://...-dev-ed.scratch.my.salesforce.com",
  "orgId": "...",
  "username": "test-...@example.com",
  "isDevHub": false,
  "instanceApiVersion": "56.0",
  "isDefaultDevHubUsername": false,
  "isDefaultUsername": false,
  "connectedStatus": "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\...." <-- massive string here
},
{
  "username": "...",
  "accessToken": ...,
  "instanceUrl": "https://...-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com",
  "orgId": "...",
  "isDevHub": true,
  "isSandbox": false,
  "isScratch": false,
  "tracksSource": false,
  "isDefaultDevHubUsername": false,
  "isDefaultUsername": false,
  "connectedStatus": "Connected"
}
```

I saved that markup and got page on the screenshot below.

[image: connected status handle output]

My problem here is that because of this output I cannot use console to check my current org. Is it a known problem? If so, when is it expected to be fixed? If not, is there a way to hide connected status other than parsing output for the data of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. You can find the answer [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2533). Try install @salesforce/cli@2.16.5 or newer.